# How do I allow all members of a domain to login remotely to a Windows XP Machine?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, samba, active-directory

I have a Samba server acting as a PDC. All of my users can login *locally* to any machine on the network with their Samba userID.

The problem is, when a user tries to use remote desktop to access a machine with their Samba userID, they get a "system policy does not allow you to login interactively" message.

I can fix this problem on a per-user basis by adding all of the users to the remote users list on each machine, but that would take forever. How do I tell the Windows XP machine to allow remote desktop access to **any** user with valid domain/samba account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding a user in the remote users list, add the 'Domain Users' group or some other group.

Create a script that adds a domain group the `Remote Desktop Users` group on the xp machines.

The exact details will depend on how you push settings to all the machines, on your domain.

Comment: In a typical Active Directory domain you would push these settings via group policy. Not sure if Samba has that capability though.

Comment: This isn't working... In "System Properties" -> "Remote" -> "Select Remote Users", I choose "Add", Select "Locations", choose my domain, Select "Object Types", and choose "Groups", enter the group name "Employees" (which all domain users are a member of on the Linux machine), and choose "check names". It accepts "MYDOMAIN\Employees" as valid. I click OK, and then it shows "MYDOMAIN\MyUserName" in the list of valid users. It's changing the group to just my user name when I choose OK. Am I doing this wrong?